# How to improve the performance if a parallel Java program is memory bound?

Tags: java, multithreading, optimization, parallel-processing, bandwidth

I wrote a parallel java program. It works typically:

- It takes a `String input` as input;
- Then `input` is cut into `String inputs[numThreads]` evenly;
- Each `inputs[i]` is assigned to `thread_i` to process, and generates `results[i]`;
- After all the working threads finish, the `main` thread merge the `results[i]` into `result`.

The performance data on a 10-core (physical cores) machine is as below.

```
Threads#    1 thread    2 threads   4 threads   8 threads   10 threads
Time(ms)       78           41          28          21           21
```

Note:

- the JVM warm-up time have been eliminated (first 50 runs).
- the time doesn't include threads starting/joining time.

It seems the memory bandwidth becomes the bottleneck when there are more than 8 threads.

In this case, how to further improve the performance? Is there any design issues in my parallel Java program?

To examine the cause of this scalability issue, I inserted a (meaningless computation) loop into the `process(inputs[i])` method. Here is the new data:

```
Threads#    1 thread      10 threads
Time(ms)     41000          4330
```

The new data shows good scalability for 10 threads, which in return confirms the original (without meaningless loop) has memory issue, so that its scalability is limited to 8 threads.

But anyway to circumvent this issue, like pre-loading the data into each core's local cache, or loading in batch?

Comment: You've implemented [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) (intentionally or not). Good job! Perhaps a distributed implementation (there are free ones) would let you scale this out over more computers.

Comment: I don't understand @Jack.  It looks to me that you aren't bounded by anything.  41000/10 == 4100 which is close to 4330 to account for thread overhead.  So how does it confirm the "memory issue"?

Comment: @Gray The reason I got 41000/4330 is that I inserted an extra (useless, computation) loop into the `process()` method. The original program doesn't have it, and the speedup stops at 8 threads.

Comment: So what speed did you get with 8 threads @Jack? I still think you are incorrect about memory bottleneck.  Unless you are talking about object/gc bandwidth instead of memory access bandwidth.  That I can believe.

Comment: @Gray You mean the program with inserted loop? If so, it should have linear speedup, like 5500ms. I am talking about the memory bandwidth. If you think I am incorrect, could you explain the reason a little more?

Comment: I guess I'm confused @Jack.  You keep on talking about memory bandwidth and bottlenecks.  Are you measuring this somehow?  How do you know that you are limited by memory?  Is it more than timing because I don't see any evidence of it in the timing numbers you have posted.

Comment: @Gray Here is my rational: The original program's performance scalability is limited to 8 threads. After inserting computation into it, the scalability is increased to at least 10. This implies the original program is not computation/cpu bound. As a result, we could guess it is bound by memory.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16053/discussion-between-gray-and-jackwm)

Answer (score 6):

I find it unlikely that you have a memory bandwidth issue here.  It is more likely that your run times are so short that as you approach 0 you are just mostly timing the thread startup/shutdown or the hotswap compiler optimization cycles.  Gaining relevant timing information from a Java task that runs so short is close to worthless.  The hotswap compiler and other optimizations that run initially often dominate the CPU usage early on in a class' life.  Our production applications stabilize only after minutes of live service operation.

If you can significantly increase your run times by adding more input data or by calculating the same result over and over you may get a better idea about what the optimal thread numbers are.

**Edit:**

Now that you have added timings for 1 and 10 threads over a longer period, it looks to me that you are not bound by anything since the timing seems to be fairly linear -- with some thread overhead.  41000/10 = 4100 versus 4330 for 10 threads.

Pretty good demonstration of what threading can do to a CPU bound application.  :-)

Comment: Interesting thoughts! So I measured the threads startup time. Starting 5 threads takes about 1ms. while starting 10 threads takes about 3ms.

Comment: The more I thought about it the more I think it is more likely to be hotswap compiler optimizations.  Can you [artificially] increase the run times of your threads by putting them in a loop or something @Jack?

Comment: I measured the time within a thread's `run()`. So it doesn't count the threads starting/ending overhead.

Comment: Updated in the question with new data.

Comment: So it looks like it is pretty linear with thread number?  Is that what I am seeing @Jack?  Some thread-overhead but not much?

Comment: As either the threads starting/shutdown time or JIT optimization were not counted, what reason do you think?

Answer (score 2):

How many logical cores do you have?

Consider - imagine you had one core and a hundred threads.  The work to be done is the same, it cannot be distributed over multiple cores, but now you have a great deal of thread switching overhead.

Now imagine you have say four cores and four threads.  Assuming no other bottlenecks, compute time is quartered.

Now imagine you have four cores and eight threads.  You compute time will be approximately quartered, but you'll have added some thread swapping overhead.

Be aware of hyperthreading and that it may help or hinder you, depending on the nature of the compute task.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your losses are down to switching threads. You have more threads than cores, and none need to block for slower processes, so they are getting switched in, doing a bit of work and then gettimg switched out to switch another one in. Switching threads is an expensive process, given the nature of what you appear to be doing I would have instinctively restricted the number of threads to 8 (leave two cores for the os) , and your performance numbers appear to bear me out.

Comment: The program ran on a 10-core machine. They don't need to switch often.

Comment: I really doubt that context switching is that expensive anymore @Tony.  It is really hard to even thrash a JVM these days.

Comment: @jackWM. They need to switch less often under the same load than a processor with less cores. If the thread needs limited memory and it's only required resource is a core to execute on, and all you've done is increased the need for a core, then it either thrashes, or it parks the thread until it gets more elbow room. Therefore creating more threads than you have cores isn't going to work.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That is the reason I didn't report any cases those used more than 10 threads. So in all my cases shown here, cores are enough, and no needs for switching.